# I am not able to connect the server

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have written the code to connect a server on the Internet, but implementation does not give any results nor Page php data shows

```
  RequestQueue requestQueue;
String url = " http://nooreldeen.hostkda.com/show.php ";
TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("allstudents");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = respons.getString("id");
                            String name = respons.getString("name");
                            String info = respons.getString("info");
                            textView.append(id + " - " + name + "\n" + info + "\n" + "-------------" + "\n");

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {


        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
        }
    }

    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

[This is the link page](http://nooreldeen.hostkda.com/show.php)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**ANDROID MAINFAIST**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Row_itm"></activity>
</application>
```

**It was added his volley**
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

[Result Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt3Iv.png)

Comment: remove spaces in URL. String url = "http://nooreldeen.hostkda.com/show.php";

Comment: It did, Shi has not changed

Comment: please provide internet permission as @Piyush suggested .

Answer (score 1):

Add Internet permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**EDIT**
Your Json response is wrong. It should be like:

{"allstudents":[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"poor","name":"poor","2":"www","info":"www"}]}

Comment: Even after adding them without any avail

Comment: Your json in web service response is {allstudents[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"poor","name":"poor","2":"www","info":"www"}]} which is still in wrong format. checkout json that i answered. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to check json format

Answer (score 1):

Your Json Format is wrong:

Error is:
 `org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Use Json Validator to validate the Json for example: http://jsonlint.com/
and this is showing:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   allstudents: [{     "0
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the INTERNET Permission in manifest file and run project on same network.

LIKE , laptop connected A WiFi (A is the wife name) and if u run application in mobile phone should mobile also connected to A WiFi.

if u rum application emulator din't affect the IP Address.

Comment: Please if you can add details to your answer on how to do that or how it helps.

Comment: I gave ear and also implemented a project to my mobile me and did not give me any results (only a blank Text view)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Screen_news extends Activity
{


----------
## JSON Through Read the Data And Image Diplay in Imageview  ##

    ArrayList<News_Adapter> actorsList;
    String NewsHeadline;
    News_ContactAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen__news);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.toolbar);
        final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_bar_viewname_name);
        if (myTitleText != null)
        {
            myTitleText.setText(R.string.news);
        }
        final ImageView imageback = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_back);
        imageback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });

        actorsList = new ArrayList<News_Adapter>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute(My_Url_Class.News);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new News_ContactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_news_layout, actorsList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long id)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getNewsHeadline(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent=new Intent(Screen_news.this,Screen_news_full_Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("NewsHeadline", actorsList.get(position).getNewsHeadline());
                intent.putExtra("NewsDateTime", actorsList.get(position).getNewsDateTime());
                intent.putExtra("NewsImage", actorsList.get(position).getNewsImage());
                intent.putExtra("NewsShortDesc", actorsList.get(position).getNewsShortDesc());
                intent.putExtra("NewsDescription", actorsList.get(position).getNewsDescription());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
    {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Screen_news.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("Data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        News_Adapter actor = new News_Adapter();

                        actor.setNewsHeadline(object.getString("NewsHeadline"));
                        actor.setNewsDateTime(object.getString("NewsDateTime"));
                        actor.setNewsImage(object.getString("NewsImage"));
                        actor.setNewsShortDesc(object.getString("NewsShortDesc"));
                        actor.setNewsDescription(object.getString("NewsDescription"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (ParseException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

## New Class Create News_Adapter

```
public class News_Adapter
{

    private String NewsHeadline;
    private String NewsDateTime;
    private String NewsShortDesc;


    private String NewsDescription;
    private String NewsImage;

    public News_Adapter()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public News_Adapter(String NewsHeadline, String NewsDateTime, String NewsShortDesc, String NewsDescription, String NewsImage)
    {
        super();
        this.NewsHeadline = NewsHeadline;
        this.NewsDateTime = NewsDateTime;
        this.NewsShortDesc = NewsShortDesc;
        this.NewsDescription = NewsDescription;
        this.NewsImage = NewsImage;
    }

    public String getNewsHeadline()
    {
        return NewsHeadline;
    }

    public void setNewsHeadline(String newsHeadline)
    {
        NewsHeadline = newsHeadline;
    }

    public String getNewsDateTime()
    {
        return NewsDateTime;
    }

    public void setNewsDateTime(String newsDateTime)
    {
        NewsDateTime = newsDateTime;
    }

    public String getNewsShortDesc()
    {
        return NewsShortDesc;
    }

    public void setNewsShortDesc(String newsShortDesc)
    {
        NewsShortDesc = newsShortDesc;
    }

    public String getNewsDescription()
    {
        return NewsDescription;
    }

    public void setNewsDescription(String newsDescription)
    {
        NewsDescription = newsDescription;
    }

    public String getNewsImage()
    {
        return NewsImage;
    }

    public void setNewsImage(String newsImage)
    {
        NewsImage = newsImage;
    }
}
```

## New Class Create News_ContactAdapter

```
public class News_ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News_Adapter> {
    ArrayList<News_Adapter> actorList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public News_ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<News_Adapter> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Text_Title);
            holder.tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Text_Time_Date);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        //holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.about_img_us);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(My_Url_Class.NEWS_IMAGE_URL + actorList.get(position).getNewsImage());
        holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getNewsHeadline());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(actorList.get(position).getNewsDateTime());
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDescription;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        ImageView imageview;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage)
        {
            this.imageview = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try
            {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
        {
            imageview.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: (My_URL_Class.News is the address of coomnuity app) you need like this , 192.168.0.62/community/services/matrimony_service.php This Address have JSON Details.

And, Connected To Smart WiFi Netwroks you have to connect mobile in smart WiFi Network.